# "stdin: is not a tty" error in Cyberduck

Tags: ssh, command-line, scp

I'm using cyberduck (GUI SCP client).

Via Command I'm sending:

```
chown -R username:username path/sp_furnicom17
```

Getting the following error:

```
stdin: is not a tty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you execute the same command in an SSH client, does it display any prompt?

Comment: Btw, note that Cyberduck is not SCP client.

Comment: I don't have the option in cPanel, i'll try to install WinSCP via CrossOver then. So i'll come back to it.

Comment: **Local** SSH client on your client machine. This has nothing to do with cPanel, nor WinSCP.

Answer (score 3):

Usually a message like

```
stdin: is not a tty
```

when using things like `scp`, `rsync` or SFTP means that there is something in the target system's login scripts that assumes that all sessions will have a TTY. This is not true: non-interactive logins, like `scp`, `rsync` or SFTP will do, will not have a TTY.

If your login scripts have anything that attempts to change terminal settings or perform any other input/output, it should be made conditional to whether the session has a TTY or not. For example, if your `~/.[bash_]profile` or `.bashrc` script has these commands:

```
echo "Today's fortune cookie:"
fortune
```

they should be changed to:

```
if tty -s
then
    echo "Today's fortune cookie:"
    fortune
fi
```